# Как записать структуру в бинарный файл?

Tags: c, файлы, двусвязный-список

есть двусвязный список, с помощью него считывается/записывается информация в бинарный файл

```
typedef struct data{
    char name[16];
    char sex[16];
    char sport[16];
    int  birthday;
    int  growth;
}dataT;

typedef struct node{
    dataT* data;
    struct node* next, *prev;
}node;

typedef struct hwnd{
    size_t size;
    node*  head, *tail;
}hwnd;  

int main(int agrc, char** argv)
{
    char s[16], c; int x;
    hwnd* hwnd = createHwnd();
    FILE* file = fopen("vector", "rb+");
    unloadData_FromFile(file, hwnd);
   
    //список обновляется, перезаписываем файл

    file = fopen("vector", "wb+");
    uploadData_ToFIle(file, hwnd->head);
    return 0;
}
```

функции считывания записи

```
void unloadData_FromFile(FILE* file, hwnd* hwnd)
{
    dataT* pData = (dataT*)malloc(sizeof(dataT)); //память под данные узла
    while(fread(pData, sizeof(dataT), 1, file))
    {
        node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //память под узел
        temp->data = pData;
        uploadList(temp, hwnd);//добавляем узел в список
    }
    fclose(file);
    return;
}

void uploadData_ToFIle(FILE* file, node* head)
{
    while(head){
        fwrite(head->data, sizeof(dataT), 1, file);
        head = head->next;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Считывание из файла в структуру работает, запись из структуры в файл работает не корректно (н-р, было 9 записей в структуре, в файл 9 раз запишется последний элемент)
Почему так происходит?

```
void uploadList(node* temp, hwnd* hwnd){
    temp->prev = hwnd->tail;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (hwnd->tail)
        hwnd->tail->next = temp;
    else
        hwnd->head = temp;
    hwnd->tail = temp;
}
```

Comment: Для начала надо закрывать FILE после unloadData_FromFile

Comment: так закрывается после чтения, в функции

Comment: Функция должна реализовывать одну фцнкцию, - читать/писать. Иначе, по Вашей логике надо передавать в фунцию имя файла - так логичнее. Там открыли/считали/закрыли

Comment: Похоже у Вас uploadList(temp, hwnd); не корректно работает

Comment: Все верно, но в этой задаче мне удобно  было так сделать...однако вопрос немного не об этом

Comment: uploadList(temp, hwnd); покажите

Comment: добавил в самый низ

Comment: Нет, ошибка в fread(), а конкретно в том, что pData инициализируется один раз вне цикла и в него запихиваются поочередно данные для каждого узла. Если переделать функцию на поэлементное считывание и инициализировать для каждого узла отдельно, все работает. https://pastebin.com/NMJiX5wM Что-то очень колхозно функция тогда выглядит, надо как-то исправить.. И почему нельзя перезаписывать в одну структуру данные мне почему-то тоже непонятно

Comment: Помому, что эта структура расположена в по одному и тому же адресу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пара замечаний:

- в случае ошибки при чтении в функции `unloadData_FromFile()` у вас происходит утечка памяти, т.к. `pData` не удаляется
- неправильно обрабатывается возврат функции `fread()`. Правильно проверять что считалось нужное количество байт, а всё остальное - ошибка. В случае ошибки чтения не обязательно вернется `0` [fread()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

И кстати, возврат функции `fwrite()` тоже нужно проверять, но там ошибки реже бывают.
Да и выделение памяти желательно проверить.

Ещё как вариант - вы можете в `struct node` держать не указатель на объект `struct data`, а сам объект. Тогда у вас повысится быстродействие - вместо 2 операций `new` (а они дорогие!) останется только одна. И чтение данных будет выглядеть также, как и запись:

```
typedef struct node
{
    dataT data; // объект, а не указатель
    struct node *next, *prev;
} node;

void unloadData_FromFile(FILE* file, hwnd* hwnd)
{
    while(true)
    {
        node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //память и под узел и под данные
        // выделение памяти тоже желательно проверить вот здесь!
        if( fread( &(temp->data), sizeof(dataT), 1, file) == sizeof(dataT) ) 
            uploadList(temp, hwnd);//добавляем узел в список
        else
        {
            delete temp;
            return;
        }
    }
}

void uploadData_ToFIle(FILE* file, node* head)
{
    while(head){
        fwrite( &(head->data), sizeof(dataT), 1, file);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас создается указатель в памяти, куда вы пишете считываемые из файла данные.

```
dataT* pData = (dataT*)malloc(sizeof(dataT)); //память под данные узла
```

При этом в новый узел, вставляемый в список, вы данные не копируете, а просто указываете на них:

```
    temp->data = pData;
```

Результат - вы получаете 9 узлов, указатель на данные которых указывает на одно и то же место в памяти. Понятно, что при каждом чтении из файла данные перезаписываются, вот вы и получаете 9 последних записей.

Попробуйте копировать данные:

```
node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //память под узел
temp->data = (dataT*)malloc(sizeof(dataT));
memcpy(temp->data,pData,sizeof(dataT));
uploadList(temp, hwnd);//добавляем узел в список
```

Comment: Вместо копирования проще в цикле читать данные в новую выделенную память.

Comment: @DmitryK Я пытался обойтись минимальными изменениями его кода.